# InfluxDB continues to connect to 104.131.151.204 with reporting-disabled = true

Tags: influxdb

We have set the flag `'reporting-disabled = true'` in `/etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf` to prevent **InfluxDB** from sending usage data. however, we still see connections to InfluxDB `usage.influxdata.com` **(ip: 104.131.151.204)** when running `tcpdump`.
Does anyone know why InfluxDB is still connecting to this server? Is there any way to completely stop InfluxDB from sending data back to their servers?

Comment: You sure you are actually using this config file?

Comment: I started a `tcpdump ... host 104.131.151.204` and will run it 24h...

Comment: Interestingly enough, I can confirm that there seem to be connections made. I will double check in a lab environment and try to inspect the payload.

Comment: Please see https://gist.github.com/mwmahlberg/62762432bfa45cca45a6ec62848f86ed for reference.